# Initialize a string object in a struct (II)

Tags: c++, string

This is a follow-up question from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403870/initialize-a-string-object-in-a-struct?noredirect=1#comment48896180_30403870), where I have a struct like

```
struct {
    int a;
    //other fields
    string s1;
    string s2;
} strMyStruct;
```

How would I initialize all members if the object is malloc() by someone else and passed it to me for quick processing (in a function `myFunc` that I am in charge of). How do I make sure in function `myFunc` that numerical members are initialized to be 0,  string members are initialized to be empty string?

```
strMyStruct *p = (strMyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(x1));
myFunc(p);
```

**UPDATE 1**

Since the members of the struct may change frequently, I don't want my code to refer to any individual members.

Comment: Don't! We just told you in the other thread not to use `malloc` like this, it's not safe! If you initialize as `strMyStruct x1{}` as we said in the other question, it will do exactly what you are describing

Comment: @CoryKramer,  this sounds crazy, but I am the poor guy got passed the block of memory that's large enough the struct and made sure all members are initialized before doing something else :-( .

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to do this. If you instantiate the variable as I mentioned, **the values will have exactly what you are asking for**

Comment: Run [this code](http://cpp.sh/4byi), all the members are initialized!

Comment: @CoryKramer,  in previous question, your answer solves my problem when I declare a local object.   Here,  I am just passed a block of memory that's of size of the struct, how do I invoke the constructor?  placement new?

Comment: Yes, your code works (that's why I accepted your answer in previous question :-) ).  However,  in this question, the situation is slightly different, I don't get to declare a local object.  I am going to accept the placement solution by @Bill Lynch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terrible idea. You really should be allocating this object with `new` instead of `malloc()`.

But if we have to, we can use placement new to allocate a C++ object in a preallocated piece of memory:

```
strMyStruct *p = (strMyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(*p));
new(p) strMyStruct;
```

And make sure you call the destructor before you call `free()`:

```
p->~strMyStruct();
free(p);
```

Comment: This is a horrific idea. `unique_ptr` at least...

Comment: @Puppy: I have no idea how `unique_ptr` solves this problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Step one: make_unique factory takes care of all this crap for you. Step two: destructor guarantees correct cleanup. Step three: move-only guarantees safety, e.g. exceptions. Simply allocating the object with `new` is a trivially tiny part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Lynch, your solution works! Will accept it in a few minutes when SO allows it.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended by @BillLynch, you need to use placement new. You can make his suggestion safer by using something along the lines of

```
std::unique_ptr<strMyStruct, placement_deleter> uptr = new(p) strMyStruct;
```

where placement_deleter is

```
struct placement_deleter {
   void operator()(strMyStruct *pointer) const {pointer->~strMyStruct()};
}
```

See if this works...

Comment: It doesn't apply to my situation where I need to do something on the fields from the memory block passed on to me, but I like it, so I up-voted it :-)

Comment: Oh - you need to return an initialized object? Ouch.